# pattern matching array with Either

Tags: scala

Say I have some code:

```
def foo(s:String):Either[Bar, Baz] = // some code here ...
```

I want to use it as:

```
val a = Array("a", "b", "c")
a.map(foo) match {
   case something => // should match when all elements in array are of type Right
   case _ =>
}
```

Can anyone suggest code for "something"

EDIT: Prefer to match and use array of `Right[Bar,Baz]` directly rather than having to extract after match.

Comment: Either will do. `Either.RightProjection[Baz]` will be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `forall` method to check that all elements in the array are `isRight`:

```
a.map(foo) match {
  case eithers if eithers.forall(_.isRight) =>
  case _ =>
}
```

Regarding your comment, if you want the match and convert-to-right all in one pass, then try a custom extractor:

```
object RightArrayExtractor {
  def unapply(eithers: Array[Either[Bar, Baz]]) =
    eithers.foldLeft(Option(Vector[Right[Bar, Baz]]())) {
      case (Some(z), x @ Right(_)) => Some(z :+ x)
      case (None, _) => None
      case (_, Left(x)) => None
    }
}

a.map(foo) match {
  case RightArrayExtractor(eithers) => // eithers is a Vector[Right[Bar,Baz]]
  case _ =>
}
```

Comment: that solves part of the problem. I want to filter and use at the same time.. so now I have `case eithers if eithers.forall(_.isRight) => eithers.map(_.right)`. I would have liked `case a:Array[Right[Baz]] => // do something with a`.

Comment: @dhs. Thanks. Saw the update. Waiting a bit to see if any other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the convenience of `collect` to change the array to the `Right` type (no pun intended) and the fact that the collected array will have the same size if all elements are `Right`:

```
a.map(foo).collect{case r@Right(_) => r} match {
  case a1 if a1.size == a.size =>
    // do something with a1 of type Array[Right[Bar,Baz]]
  case _ => 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are very good and this example isn't that practical as the others. I'd just like to add a bit of underlying theory.

What you're describing is often called **traversal** in functional programming. You have a collection like `Seq[X]` and a monadic (or applicative) computation `X => M[Y]`. Standard `map` gives you `Seq[M[Y]]`, but traversal gives you `M[Seq[Y]]`.

In this case, the monadic computation is something that produces `Either[Error,Right]`, in this case `M[_]` is `Either[Error,_]`. So if you just map over a collection with such a function, you get `Seq[Either[Error,Right]]`. But what you want is `Either[Error,Seq[Right]]` and that's exactly what traversal does. If the function fails on any element of the sequence (returns `Left(something)`) then the final result is just this `Left(something)`. If the function succeeds on all the elements (returns `Right(...)` for all of them) then the final result is `Right(sequenceOfResults)`.

Scala doesn't have a built-in function for that, but [Scalaz](https://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) does, it's called `traverse`. A complete example:

```
import scalaz._;
import Scalaz._;
import Applicative._;

object RightMatch extends App {
  // our example function
  def foo(s: String): Either[String,Int] =
    if (s.startsWith("a")) Right(s.length)
    else Left("wrong: " + s);

  // We make an utility function for traversing Sequences wit Eithers:
  def traverseRight[X,L,R](es: Seq[X], f: X => Either[L,R]): Either[L,Seq[R]] = {
    // we need to convert Either to Either.RightProjection
    type RightF[Y] = Either.RightProjection[L,Y];
    es.traverse[RightF,R](x => f(x).right).e; // and back to Either
  }

  // Or, if we just want to convert an existing sequence of eithers:
  def traverseRight[L,R](es: Seq[Either[L,R]]): Either[L,Seq[R]] =
    traverseRight(es, identity[Either[L,R]]);

  {
    val a = Seq("a", "ab", "ac");
    traverseRight(a, foo) match {
      case Right(arr) => println(arr); // we get the array of Ints here
      case Left(err)  => println(err); // we get String here (the first error)
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that in Scalaz `Array` has not an implementation of traversable (I don't know why), so I used `Seq` instead.)

As mentioned, traversal applies not just to `Either`s, it applies to any monadic computations. So the same approach can be used for a vast range of problems, like sequencing stateful computations (modelled by scalaz's `State`), sequencing non-deterministic computations (the `List` monad) etc.